# How to disable null device while usin dev.off() in R and latex?

Tags: sweave, r

How to disable message null device when using R and latex.

```
<<echo=FALSE ,results=tex>>=
data<-read.table("test",sep="\t",header=TRUE,check.names=FALSE)
names(data)<-substr(names(data),1,20)
pdf("image.pdf")
par(las=2)
par(mar=c(2,12,2,2))
barplot(as.matrix(disease_data),beside=TRUE, col=c("burlywood1 ","orange2"), horiz=TRUE,cex.names=1.0, border ="white")
dev.off()
@
```

I have already disable echo but null device is on image. How can i avoid it?

Regards
Regards

Answer (score 2):

`echo=FALSE` only hides the R code; if you want to hide the output, you should use `results=hide`.

But why do you have to use `pdf()` and `dev.off()` to manually create a PDF plot? This is too awkward. You should leave this job to Sweave.

Comment: Now i am using sweave but i can not reduce image size that is why i am using includegraphics by passing width and height to control its size. Is there any way to reduce plot size in R?

Comment: yes, that is one of the tiny reasons which motivated my `knitr` package, which allows you to control the size of your plots easily; see http://yihui.name/knitr/ or the manual https://github.com/downloads/yihui/knitr/knitr-manual.pdf